# Media Queries Hide DIV Via Max-Width

Tags: css

http://jsbin.com/regovusu/1/edit

I've been building a WYSIWYG Website Designer and I had some time today to incorporate media queries.

I have 3 divs setup, `.mobile`, `.tablet`, and `.desktop`.

The plan is if the browser is `400px or lower` to show the `.mobile` div,
`400px` to `600px` to show `.tablet`,
and `600px` + to show `.desktop`

I'm not sure why this is not responding.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**The CSS**:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mobile, .tablet {
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width:400px) { 
  .tablet, .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) { 
  .mobile, .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use media queries with max-width, you should always include the larger values above the lower values because you want the smaller width to override the larger width.

```
/* common rules always active */

@media all and (max-width:400px) { 
    /* this will only shows when the max width is 400 */
}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {
    /* this will only show when the max width is 600,
    but it will override the 400 view  because when the
    max width is 600, it is always greater than 400 */
}
```

To avoid this issue, you need to move your 600 block above the 400 block.

```
/* common rules always active */

@media all and (max-width:600px) {

}

@media all and (max-width:400px) { 
    /* now the 400 block will override the 600 view
    when the max width is less than 400 */
}
```

The second part is you'll need to reset the display property in the mobile and tablet views. e.g. `display:block`

Here is a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/4xaFe/